# Search for strings featuring 'X in Y' ratios using RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I am looking for strings that feature `X in Y` ratios, (e.g., `1 in 2`, `2 in 3`). I would like my search to also capture ratios with words in between, like in `1 woman in 4` or `1 person with this feature in 5`...

I came up with this:

```
ratio = re.findall('[0-9]+[^\.]*? in [^\.]+?[0-9]+', corpus)
```

But this is capturing cases that I do not want, like for example:

> this person was **1 of them. This was good because in general 5** of them...
>
> #**123 @ George: this was just in case of 5** people being interested...

Comment: Try `ratio = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\s*\w+)? in(?:\s*\w+)? [0-9]+', corpus)`.

Comment: A question about edit: Do you want save these `**` like now, or just want to show these text as **bold** like before?

Comment: Your regex does not match the first "wrong" string (because you specified that dots may not occur between the two numbers). If you add a `:` to the negated character class, the second example wouldn't match either. But *exactly* what kind of text is allowed or forbidden between numbers is something only you can decide - and need to specify explicitly so a fitting regex can be built.

Comment: This seems like one of those "ten years and a research team" problems. "I bought 12 candy bars and in 6 of them I found caramel" will match to "12 candy bars and in 6" even though it's not a ratio. You would need some kind of full-fledged natural language processing engine to filter these out.

Comment: You can't do this in pure regex. You must determine what the meaning of `in` in the sentence is. For example, this is not a ratio: `5 men in their 60s are running the marathon today`

Comment: The first case has a `.` before the `in`. So, it won't match. And to avoid matching the second case you can use `[^.:]` instead of `[^\.]`. Another _idea_  would be reject upper case letters.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much to all of you. I adapted just a bit the regex proposed by @Strubizhev (just added a * so that we can capture 1 woman aged more than 40 in 10...): [0-9]+(?:\s*\w+)+? in(?:\s*\w+)? [0-9]+. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Kevin Guan: I just wanted those in bold.

Comment: @Zoff Dino: The problem you raise is a tough one because 'in' is always a 'general preposition', so even if I would tag the corpus I am using, it would not help... I guess I will simply decide 'by hand' which ones are relevant.